# Which submarine was invented first?

Tags: technology, ottoman-empire, submarine

In some books I saw the Ottomans invented Tahtelbahir in 1719. Is it true ?

Comment: The claim seems to be made in [this paper](http://www.muslimheritage.com/uploads/Rocket_Technology_in_Turkish_history1.pdf) by Arslan Terzioglu (p12). I'm not sure that I'd agree with his definition of "strong evidence" though. This may be a better fit on skeptics:SE

Comment: Downvote for uncited source.

Comment: There seem to have been a number of [earlier attempts at submarines](http://www.submarine-history.com/NOVAone.htm#1623) than this Ottoman example. However, most of them (including the Tahtelbahir) would not be considered proper submarines by modern standards. See also [this earlier question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8973/the-first-use-of-submarines-and-the-appearance-of-modern-submarines?rq=1).

Comment: Alexandr of Macedonia invented a submarine even earlier.

Answer (score 12):

The first submarine was developed by [Cornelis Drebbel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornelis_Drebbel), a Dutchman, in 1620. 
The first submarine that went into action was [the Turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_(submersible)), developed by [David Bushnell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Bushnell) in 1776. It went in action, but never sank a ship. The first submarine to do that was the [Hunley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._L._Hunley_(submarine)) in 1864. (With the loss of the submarine, and its entire crew).

The first modern submarine that went into service was the [Holland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holland-class_submarine), invented by John Holland in 1903.

I disregard earlier inventions, such as that of Alexander the Great, because those are not documented, and non-propelled vessels such as diving bells (or diving clocks). Diving bells are relatively easy to construct, and were in use long before submarines. They are **not** submarines.

The first Turkish submarine was a [Nordenfelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorsten_Nordenfelt) in 1886. I can't find anything at all before. It's not impossible this Tahtelbahir made a submerged vessel, but his wouldn't be the first. That honor goes to Drebbel. Further reading on Nordenfelt [here](http://maviboncuk.blogspot.com/2008/03/ottoman-submarines-from-1700s.html).

Comment: you forgot one of the first modern-working submarines, air independent, the Ictineus, from Barcelona. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ict%C3%ADneo_II

Answer (score 2):

The first submarine that was successful enough to warrant widespread adoption, changing the nature of naval warfare forever, was built by John Holland. His basic design is still in use today.

There were underwater vessels built before Holland's design, but none were successful enough to warrant widespread adoption. Arguably, methods to travel underwater date back to the time of Alexander, who was recorded to have dove into the Med using an early [diving bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_bell).

Holland benefited from two technical advancements that filled in the missing pieces: sustainable power under water (electric motors and batteries), and a safer (for the crew of the submarine) method of attack, the Whitehead torpedo.

It is now believed that the crew of the CSS Hunley were killed or incapacitated by the [underwater shock of the explosion](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/08/170823140703.htm), when the explosive charge detonated prematurely, with the Hunley still next to the USS Housatonic, so an effective military submarine really couldn't have been built before the self powered torpedo was available.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the definition of "submarine". By the very same wikipedia page on Cornelis Drebbel, it is now believed the accounts of the time were greatly exagerated and the ship was neither completely submergible, nor capable of independent propulsion, relying on the Thames currents to make the crossing of the river.

**Jos** cited the Holland submarine as the first modern submarine "that went into service". Without that last clause, other modern submarines were built before, like [the one built by Isaac Peral in 1888](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Peral).

Comment: you have the date for Peral wrong